# GAE Flex Custom Runtime random shutdown

Tags: google-app-engine

I'm running a very simple node app in a GAE Flex custom instance instance.

All of a sudden, seemingly out of nowhere, it shuts down causing a short period of 503s, before eventually coming back up:

[image]

I'm absolutely certain nobody did this manually.

What's going on? Are GAE apps expected to randomly shut down and restart?

Here's my config:

```yaml
runtime: custom
api_version: '1.0'
env: flexible
threadsafe: true
automatic_scaling:
  cool_down_period: 120s
  min_num_instances: 1
  max_num_instances: 15
  cpu_utilization:
    target_utilization: 0.5
network: {}
liveness_check:
  initial_delay_sec: 300
  path: /
  check_interval_sec: 30
  timeout_sec: 4
  failure_threshold: 4
  success_threshold: 2
readiness_check:
  path: /
  check_interval_sec: 5
  timeout_sec: 4
  failure_threshold: 2
  success_threshold: 2
  app_start_timeout_sec: 300
```

Comment: It seems for me that your app is failing due to **readiness check** which is intended to tell that your instance is ready to accept incoming requests and because your instance is failing to pass this check it's being terminated and restarted. I noticed that the readiness check flag is set so I would suggest change this props **"check_interval_sec"**, **"timeout_sec"** and **"app_start_timeout_sec"** to a higher time.

Comment: Ok, thanks. But the sentences "shutdown initiated" and "beginning service lameduck" occur before the readiness checks start (and fail). What could be initiating the shutdown?

Comment: I recommend you verify if the app had latency in that period of time since a high rate of 503 errors typically means that an instance has exceeded resources available to it. I think that shutdown is related to the 503 error . Other thing is that Flexible has no controls for concurrency so requests may overload an instance so you can monitor concurrency on the instance and shunt requests to a handler returning 503 when the number gets too high. Finally, Is the instance still sending 503 errors?

Comment: This was a one time occurence, it stopped sending 503s right after the restart was completed

Comment: There was not a lot of traffic, som hard to see it that it could have been an overload

Comment: "typically means that an instance has exceeded resources available to it" What kind of resources? Memory? High cpu load should just have caused it to spawn a new instance, right?

Comment: Same exact thing happened again. Not seeing any big change resource use. Gonna try to give more memory

Comment: I recommend you  open a support case since the team can inspect deeply your project and the resources :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that GAE flex instances automatically reboot once a week. So when you have only one instance running, this behaviour is to be expected.

Comment: I have the same problem with automatic_scaling:  min_num_instances: 2 max_num_instances: 2. Did you have this problem after increasing the number of your instances?

Comment: I think it still appears in the log, but I doesn't route traffic to the instance that is resetting, so I no longer experience downtime

Comment: I have some POST requests with 502 http code when rebooting. Don't you have it?

Comment: No, not after setting minimum instances to 2